# How to debug sphinx?

Tags: debugging, sphinx

I want to see how sphinx actually works,has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about "Sphinx - the free open-source SQL full-text search engine", then the answer is pretty simple: Go ahead and have a look at [the source code](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz) :)

Comment: I've downloaded the source code,but don't know how to debug the giant

Comment: You have got to be more specific. First, why do you need to debug it?

Comment: Debug is the best way to get familiar with the code,and I need to customize it later.

Comment: Ok. But what is your question, then? How to build the project? How to attach a debugger? Anyway, you will have to tell us how far you are and what problems you are facing.

Comment: I'm looking for information about all you mentioned above,I need to set a breakpoint for sphinx to dive further into it.